# libc crate doesn't provide sprintf on Windows

Tags: windows, rust, libc

I wrote a library in Rust that uses C formatting using the `sprintf` function provided by the libc crate. Everything works on macOS and Linux but it does not compile on Windows because the `sprintf` function does not exist.

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::{c_char, c_double, sprintf};
```

```
let c_resfmt: CString =
    CString::new(c_resfmt).expect("Couldn't convert to c_resfmt to CString ");
let result_buffer: *mut c_char = CString::new("").expect("").into_raw();
unsafe {
    sprintf(result_buffer, c_resfmt.as_ptr(), scaled_result as c_double);
    let formatted_result = CString::from_raw(result_buffer).into_string().unwrap();
    ptr_result.with_result_value(formatted_result);
}
```

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `libc::sprintf`
  --> src\stdf_helper\reader\mod.rs:12:13
   |
12 | use libc::{ sprintf, c_char, c_double };
   |             ^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             no `sprintf` in the root
   |             help: a similar name exists in the module: `isprint`
```

Is there a substitute or alternative name for this?

Comment: As best I can tell, your code is **completely broken**. You are writing your formatted data into a zero-length string, overwriting arbitrary data. Try running your code under a tool like Valgrind.

Comment: Independently of your compilation problem, `sprintf` assumes its first argument is a large enough buffer (which is not your case!). It's a broken function that you cannot use safely.

Comment: It appears not to be bound. Check [libc issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/issues) and possibly file one. That said, the point of rust is avoiding memory unsafety and `sprintf` is probably the biggest offender in C, nearly impossible to use correctly. Can't you use a more modern formatting function instead?

Comment: It looks like you just want to write C in Rust.. so why not just write C?

Comment: The business logic of the project contains some C formatting specifiers that cannot be applied to Rust format!. I've written my own logic that applies to that but I'm thinking that I cannot cover all the edge cases: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6518824cce93899429056abb8657be19 . One edge case that crossed my mind is for an input let's say 3242.32 formatted with %6d. Compare the results from C and Rust: https://code.sololearn.com/cHerGNWry1nb

Answer (score -3):

This is probably a toolchain thing.

You are probably using the GNU toolchain on macOS and Linux (*Nix)

Make sure you got the latest and greatest MSVC toolchain installed and used

Read [this article](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/platform-and-target-support/msvc-toolchain-support.html) for more information

> The difference between the two matters for interacting with C. If
> you're using a library built with one toolchain or another, you need
> to match that with the appropriate Rust toolchain. If you're not sure,
> go with MSVC; it's the default for good reason.

Use MSVC on windows.

Comment: If you read libc platform specific documentation, you will notice that sprintf is not present in the exported functions: https://rust-lang.github.io/libc/x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/libc/index.html

Comment: @Mr. Carter that’s the platform specific docs for windows on the gnu toolchain. I can’t find documentation for x86_64 windows using the MSVC toolchain. But I can find sprintf in the libc docs, Here it is  https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.63/libc/fn.sprintf.html. Seems like it’s platform specific. Changing to x86_64 windows using the MSVC toolchain from x86_64 windows using the GNU toolchain could solve the issue as suggested in the answer above.